# Integrate GCP with OpsGenie for Alerts

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, monitoring, opsgenie

It may be a vague question but I couldn't find any documentation regarding the same. Does Google cloud platform have provision to integrate with OpsGenie?

Basically we have set up few alerts in GCP for our `Kubernetes Cluster monitoring` and we want them to be feeded to `OpsGenie` for Automatic call outs in case of high priority incidents.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked at https://support.atlassian.com/opsgenie/docs/integrate-opsgenie-with-google-stackdriver/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recapping for better visibility:

OpsGenie supports multiple [tools](https://www.atlassian.com/software/opsgenie/integrations), including Google Stackdriver.
Instruction on how to integrate it with Stackdriver webhooks can be found [here](https://support.atlassian.com/opsgenie/docs/integrate-opsgenie-with-google-stackdriver/).